# What's the easiest way to edit a dependency in a gem stored on GitHub

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, github, rubygems

I'm trying to install a `gem` from GitHub, but in the gemspec a dependency version makes installing the gem impossible. All I need is to edit that version.

What's the easiest way of doing this so I can make the gem usable in my app ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fork it, modify the `gemspec` by changing the version of dependency and after that to install this gem in your app by defining

`gem 'your_gem', :git => 'git://github.com/your_name/your_gem.git`

Comment: This is, unfortunately, the best approach unless you can get that dependency resolved by the original author.